# Reading Excel files from WebDAV server in R

Tags: r, webdav

I try to access some Excel files via remote connection to the WebDAV server running on my NAS using R. I couldn't find any promising way to read directly from the server, so I want to download the files before reading them in.

What I tried so far is the following:

**Version 1**

```
library(httr)

df <- GET("https://my/fille/path.xlsx",
          authenticate("my_user", "my_pw", "any"))

str(content(df))
```

With this code I could establish a connection but got `raw [1:23161] 50 4b 03 04 ...` as output.

**Version 2**

```
library(httr)
library(readxl)

# save the excel file to disk
GET("https://my/fille/path.xlsx",
    authenticate("my_user", "my_pw", "any"),
    write_disk(df <- "tmp.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE))

# save to dataframe
df <- read_excel(df, 1L)
df
```

This gave me the following output

```
Response [https://my/file/path.xlsx]
  Date: 2023-01-10 21:13
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
  Size: 23.2 kB
<ON DISK>  /directory/file.xlsx
```

When trying to read this file it doesn't work and it is also not possible to open it with excel.

Are there any specific options I am missing in the GET function call or am I actually very far away from what I want?
Port forwarding and access rights for the particular user are set and I can connect via other applications without any problem.

Comment: When you use `write_disk`, can you verify that the file is created on disk? Does it have the right file size (number of bytes)? Can you open the file in excel?

Comment: I edited `write_disk` - I did not test the initial version. `write_disk(df <- "tmp.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)` creates a file that cannot be opened in excel.

Comment: What is the size of the file on disk? The Version 1 code seemed to return 23,161 bytes that started with "50 4b 03 04" which is the expected magic number for an xslx file. What error does Excel give you when you try to open the file?

Comment: Initially, tmp.xlsx had 0 kB and excel said there is no file to read. However, when trying to reproduce the error, it disappeared. Not sure why but Version 2 works without any problems now. Thanks for your time!